# Is it possible to run groovy method in stage block without wrapping it in a steps block (Declarative syntax)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to get a Jenkinsfile to "generate" stages with the help of groovy methods. The main issue I have is that it does not allow you to run the method call in the stage without wrapping it in a 'steps' block, which makes it impossible to use it for defining an agent that uses docker, or to create dynamic stages (because they are not allowed in the steps block). The main reason I need this is because the Jenkinsfile we have currently has a lot of stages (each step requires a docker agent/worker) which causes way too much code duplication and makes it hard to maintain and add new stuff.

My experimental file looks like this

```
def generateStage(bar) {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'ubuntu:latest'
        }
    }
    stage ("${bar}") {
        steps {
            sh "echo running in ${bar}"
        }
    }

}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Main') {
            steps {
                generateStage("foo")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to hack around this?
Jenkins throws this error when you remove the 'steps' block wrapping generateStage("foo")

```
Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block.
```

Comment: If your method is defining the pipeline at the `stage` level, then it also needs to be invoked at the `stage` level within your pipeline, and not at a lower scope. Give that a try and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: I’ve tried to run it directly beneath the ‘stages’ block, but that doesn’t work either because it expects stage, parallel or a steps block. Is that what you meant?